# How to route two different paths to the same server using apache

Tags: apache, server, http-proxy

Consider two urls:

1. www.mysite.com/*
2. www.mysite.com/browse/*

The backend runs at  http://localhost:8080

How can I make sure that all requests with following pattern will end up at my backend like below?

**Example**:

www.mysite.com/doA   --> localhost:8080/doA

www.mysite.com/browse/doA --> localhost:8080/doA

So basically both www.mysite.com/doA and www.mysite.com/browse/doA result in the same thing.

I want to use apache server. I can redirect one using proxy_http. But it doesn't work for two or more urls:

This is my config that work for one url

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ProxyPass         /  http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPassReverse  /  http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyRequests     Off
  <Proxy http://localhost:8080/*>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName example.com
ProxyRequests     Off
ProxyPass         /browse/ http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPass         /        http://localhost:8080/
ProxyPassReverse  /        http://localhost:8080/
</VirtualHost>
```

> The configured `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassMatch` rules are checked in
>   the order of configuration. The first rule that matches wins. So
>   usually you should sort conflicting `ProxyPass` rules starting with
>   the longest URLs first. Otherwise, later rules for longer URLS will be
>   hidden by any earlier rule which uses a leading substring of the URL

Comment: You are welcome. Also, you can [accept the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235).