# one server, same domain, different apps (example.com/ & example.com/tickets )?

Tags: python, wordpress, url, routes, url-routing

I want advice on how to do the following:

On the same server, I want to have two apps. One WordPress app and one Python app. At the same time, I want the root of my domain to be a static landing page.

Url structure I want to achieve:

- example.com/   => static landing page
- example.com/tickets => wordpress
- example.com/pythonapp => python app

I have never done something like this before and searching for solutions didn't help.

Is it even possible? 
Is it better to use subdomains?
Is it better to use different servers?

How should I approach this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can create sub folder inside root folder

Comment: Subfolders are a good start, next specific web server configuration changes will help. That depends on your web server, obviously.

Comment: @deceze for example, wordpress uses apache. So something like this will do it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38793447/how-to-route-two-different-paths-to-the-same-server-using-apache/38796478#38796478 
But how do I point a proxy pass to a folder?

Comment: You can run the Python script under Apache as well, using any of the common techniques to do so. Alternatively, you can *reverse-proxy* the request to any other HTTP server on which you run Python. `RewriteRule` with the `[P]` flag will do for starters.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible with php rewrite engine.
Internally the wordpress app may have some random URL, but you can modify it and show as whatever you wanted it to the users.

once have a look at this
https://www.addedbytes.com/blog/url-rewriting-for-beginners

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the webserver you want to use. Let's go with apache as it is one of the most used web servers on the internet.

1. You install your wordpress installation into the /tickets subdirectory and install word-press as you normally would. This should install wordpress into the subdirectory.
2. Configure your Python-WSGI App with this configuration:

   `WSGIScriptAlias /pythonapp /var/www/path/to/my/wsgi.py`